# Recuperar marker dentro de múltiplos mapas

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma aplicação que usa um mapa do Google e mostra múltiplos markers.
Ao lado do mapa eu listo os endereços e eu gostaria de, quando o usuário desse um `mouseover` por cada endereço, o icon do mapa mudasse.

Então eu tenho (para mostrar os markers):

```
for (var i = 0; i < lat.length-1; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i], long[i]),id:i, title: nomes[i], icon: pinImage, label: {text: ""+(i+1)+"", color: "white"} ,
        map: map
    });
```

E tenho (para capturar o `mouseover` no link):

```
$("a[data-link]").mouseover(function() {

    var idNumber = $(this).data("link");
    var novocentro = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[idNumber-1], long[idNumber-1]);
    map.setZoom(14);
    map.setCenter(novocentro);
});
```

Eu já consigo centralizar o mapa para o local e dar um zoom. Mas eu não consigo mudar o ICON do marker. Imagina que pudesse fazer algo assim:

```
marker[idNumber].setIcon = "xxxx"
```

Mas isso não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Você quase acertou, só que o `setIcon` é uma `function`, que deve ser chamada assim:

```
marker[idNumber].setIcon('nomedoicone');
```

Você pode também passar um objeto do tipo `Icon` ou `Symbol`.

Veja mais em: [Google Maps Javascript API - #Marker.setIcon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/marker?hl=pt-BR#Marker.setIcon)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Mas ainda está faltando algo. Estou edidanto, minuto ....

Comment: Se eu puser logo abaixo de
map.setCenter(novocentro); isso: marker[idNumber].setIcon('nomedoicone'); 
(só para ver o resultado), o console me devolve um erro assim:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setIcon' of undefined

Essa trecho está dentro da função INITMAP, para constar.

O mesmo problema acontece se eu chamar por exemplo
var val = marker[1].get("title");

Ele parece não reconhece MARKER. Mas ele reconhece "map", pq map.setCenter(novocentro) funciona.

Comment: A sua variável `marker` nao existe no contexto da função. Quando está criando os markers, você deve atribuir em um Array cada um, logo, `arrayMarkers[idNumber].setIcon('nomedoicone');`. Pois a função `setIcon` pertence à um Marker apenas.

Comment: Funcionou!! Eu criei um array, joguei cada marker la pra dentro e depois foi só fazer assm: markers[idNumber-1].setIcon(pinImagehover); Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: Que bom! Marque a resposta como válida por favor. Até mais!